# Is it possible to swap an Intel motherboard setup for an AMD setup with Windows?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, compatibility

I'm changing the motherboard in one of my computers as it has failed, but I'm unsure if I could get an AMD board, which is cheaper (so I'd get more 'bang for the buck'), and do a straight swap, as the old one is an Intel-based board.

I've swapped many a motherboard and the only problems I usually get are small driver issues which can be easily resolved once Windows has booted. But AMD is completely new territory to me, so all I'm really asking is if the windows 7 installation on the hard drives will be configured to accept an AMD motherboard. I say hard drives because I think they are setup as a Raid 0 array, which I'm guessing is my biggest problem.

Comment: Most likely you'll need to boot from Windows installation media and do a repair. Other than that there's nothing peculiar about AMD.

Comment: @MichaelBay What about the fact that it's a raid 0 across two HDDs, do you think that would be a problem? I can't even remember how I set the RAID up, but I don't think it was a BIOS configuration.

Comment: Please note and understand that a comment isn't an answer. If I had the intention to answer your question I would have done it in the proper format. Instead I merely pointed out the obvious part. Now, regarding the RAID, if you don't even know how it was set, that alone makes that part pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: @MichaelBay Yes, you're right Michael. You should only use comments to ask for more information or clarification so you can make an informed answer.

Comment: See this, but there will be activation issues....https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html

Comment: But as stated, it wasn't a Motherboard-reliant RAID setup. So it was a software-based setup, the software that is still ever-present on the HDD.

Comment: @Moab Thanks Moab, that may come in handy :)